# UWP: How to override Ctrl-X, Ctrl-V, etc. in a textbox

Tags: win-universal-app

I have a text box in my app. In this app, I am creating my own Undo/Redo functionality because the text in my textbox represents something much larger in memory, and I need to track these textbox changes to be able to undo/redo the whole project properly.

As part of that, I need to capture -- and handle -- many common keyboard scenarios on my own. Yes, I know this is going to be painful.

My major hurdle at the moment is the fact that the textbox intercepts (and even hides) the "usual" keys like <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Y</kbd>. It does this so that it can implement its own undo-redo, but I don't need the built-in undo/redo stuff. I would like to completely disable these keys in my UWP app.

I know that you can do this in winforms, but UWP appears to be a different beast.

```
    private async void MyTextBox_KeyDown(object sender, KeyRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var ctrl = Window.Current.CoreWindow.GetKeyState(VirtualKey.Control).HasFlag(CoreVirtualKeyStates.Down);

        // Handle special keys!!
        if (ctrl && e.Key == Windows.System.VirtualKey.F)
        {
            Find_Click(null, null);
            e.Handled = true;
        }
        else if (ctrl && e.Key == Windows.System.VirtualKey.R)
        {
            Replace_Click(null, null);
            e.Handled = true;
        }

    ...

        else if (ctrl && e.Key == Windows.System.VirtualKey.Z)
        {
            // THIS DOES NOT FIRE
            Undo();
            e.Handled = true;
        }
        else if (ctrl && e.Key == Windows.System.VirtualKey.Y)
        {
            // THIS DOES NOT FIRE
            Redo();
            e.Handled = true;
        }
        else if (ctrl && e.Key == Windows.System.VirtualKey.X)
        {
            // THIS DOES NOT FIRE
            CaptureUndo("");
            e.Handled = true;
        }
        else if (ctrl && e.Key == Windows.System.VirtualKey.V)
        {
            // THIS FIRES, BUT THE PASTE HAS ALREADY HAPPENED
            // SO e.Handled IS USELESS
            string s=GetClipboardText();
            CaptureUndo(s);
            e.Handled = true;
        }
    }
```

I would really appreciate a nudge in the right direction.

Comment: Not a full answer, but you can handle the paste with MyTextBox.Paste += YourOverridePasteMethod(object sender, TextControlPasteEventArgs e) method.  Just mark e.Handled = true.  There does not appear to be the other functions available.

Comment: Thank you for the comment. Yes, I'd found that already. But since paste ACTUALLY fires (out of order), then the Paste() override is also useless to me.